# Return empty map when trying to read from gorilla SecureCookie

Tags: go, cookies, gorilla

I wrote functions to create a SecureCookie and read this SecureCookie following the documentation in GoDoc and gorilla api. The SecureCookie has been successfully created, and printed out, but when i was trying to read values from this encoded cookie, it returned an empty map. Can someone help me to figure out what's wrong with the code?

```
var hashKey []byte
var blockKey []byte
var s *securecookie.SecureCookie

func init() {
    hashKey = []byte{61, 55, 215, 133, 151, 242, 106, 54, 241, 162, 37, 3, 98, 73, 102, 33, 164, 246, 127, 157, 31, 190, 240, 40, 30, 104, 15, 161, 180, 214, 162, 107}
    blockKey = []byte{78, 193, 30, 249, 192, 210, 229, 31, 223, 133, 209, 112, 58, 226, 16, 172, 63, 86, 12, 107, 7, 76, 111, 48, 131, 65, 153, 126, 138, 250, 200, 46}

    s = securecookie.New(hashKey, blockKey)
}

func CreateSecureCookie(u *models.User, sessionID string, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {

    value := map[string]string{
        "username": u.Username,
        "sid":      sessionID,
    }

    if encoded, err := s.Encode("session", value); err == nil {
        cookie := &http.Cookie{
            Name:     "session",
            Value:    encoded,
            Path:     "/",
            Secure:   true,
            HttpOnly: true,
        }
        http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
    } else {
        log.Println("Error happened when encode secure cookie:", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func ReadSecureCookieValues(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (map[string]string, error) {
    if cookie, err := r.Cookie("session"); err == nil {
        value := make(map[string]string)
        if err = s.Decode("session", cookie.Value, &value); err == nil {
            return value, nil
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

Comment: map[sid:1686c951-e189-7205-52dc-e2cbb3a0e7ea username:AnnaZhao], this map is the cookie.Value before encoded, but when i wanted to get it back from the above function, it gave me back empty map..

Comment: I also tried exact same code in documentation, but also returned empty value..

Comment: Is the url using https? The `Secure` attribute is set to `true` so the cookie will only work over https.

Comment: yes. the cookie has been encoded successfully, and saved, i can see in chrome Application. but when decoding the cookie value, it returns empty...

Answer (score 0):

Errors might be silently ignored in the read function, due to block scoping.

Instead, check and return errors as soon as possible. For example:

```
func ReadSecureCookieValues(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (map[string]string, error) {

    cookie, err := r.Cookie("session")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    value := make(map[string]string)

    err = s.Decode("session", cookie.Value, &value)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return value, nil
}
```

The returned error might explain the problem. Maybe the cookie wasn't found?